# Hibernate merge() сохраняет дубликаты

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

В Spring MVC приложении я имею упрощенную модель следующего вида.
Класс User, у которого есть список файлов:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int id;

        @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "owner")
        private Set<StoredFile> storedFiles = new HashSet<>();

        //.........//

    }
```

Файлы с одинаковым именем не должны добавляться в базу. Класс файл:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stored_files")
public class StoredFile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(unique = false)
    private String name;

    private LocalDateTime time;

    @ManyToOne
    private User owner;

    private boolean shared;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof StoredFile)) return false;
        StoredFile that = (StoredFile) o;
        return  getName().equals(that.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = Objects.hash(getName());
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Я добавляю первый файл `user.getStoredFiles().add(new StoredFile(...))`, 
Обновляю юзера, CascadeType.MERGE обновляет и коллекцию `entityManger.merge(user)`
Файл появился в базе. Добавляю так же второй файл, но в базу попадает снова первый файл и второй:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если добавить третий файл, то их в базе будет уже 6. В списке `storedFiles` Элементы не дублируются, т.е. это уже происходит в недрах метода merge(). В чём может быть проблема? Пробовал ставить на имени `@Column(unique=true)` - в postgresql это срабатывает, записываются только новые файлы, на старые вылетает эксепшн, а вот в mysql после эксепшена файлы вообще не записываются в базу.

**UPDATE:**

добавление файла в методе контроллера:

```
@PostMapping("/savefile")
    @ResponseBody
    public void saveFile(@RequestParam(name = "file")MultipartFile file, @RequestParam String shared, HttpSession session){
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
        String name = file.getOriginalFilename();

        try {
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(GeneralSettings.STORED_FILES_PATH + user.getLogin() + "/" + name), file.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        user.getStoredFiles().add(new StoredFile(name, LocalDateTime.now(), user, shared.equals("1")));
        userDAO.updateUser(user);
    }
```

UserDAO:

```
@Repository("user_dao")
@Transactional
public class UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    @Transactional
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        em.merge(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: покажите код, которым вы сохраняете

Comment: Serodv, привел .

Comment: Во-первых, у вас стоит `unique = false`, это значит допускается повторение имен файлов, во-вторых, даже если вы поменяете на `true`, у вас при вставке будет просто ошибка по unique constraint. Слияние происходит по `primary key`, у вас же создается `new StoredFile`, поскольку не имеет айдишника, в базу вставляется новый элемент.

Comment: ну и как это делается правильно?

Comment: может нужно поменять стратегию генерирования id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При втором и последующем merge User вы мерджите старое значение с пустыми id в StoredFile.

Соответственно вам нужно:

1. UserDAO.updateUser возвращал новую сущность которую вернул merge и подменять ею user в сессии.

Или

2. Получать текущее состояние User из БД, добавлять записи и после записывать.